# OSX mac push notifications delay

Tags: safari, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, osx-mavericks

I am developing an app that will use mac push notifications. I got the notifications to work and all but there seems to be a lot of delay, sometimes, until the notifications reach the mac itself. I looked at the apsd logs and they seem fine, the service is able to connect but after a short time it seems it doesn't receive any notification until it tries to reconnect.
Has anyone else come across a similar issue?
Does anyone have a suggestion for fixing this?

EDIT: I would like to also add that I try my own application and a test application developed by someone else https://kandutech.net/ and also get the same delay.

Comment: How long is the delay?

Comment: Sometimes the push comes in right away sometimes it takes up to 25 minutes.
I tried testing this on a few different networks with the same result.
I don't have internal knowledge of apsd but it seems it loses connectivity without realizing it.

Comment: Can you show your push notification codes?

Comment: Sorry, it's my companies code. But it's not problematic. I have confirmation from apple that it was received (I am aware of the unreliability factor of this service) and then it takes about 20 minutes for the notification to reach the mac.

Comment: You're using Remote Notification / Local Notification?